# Configure Netty 4 with SslContext parameters

Tags: java, netty

I am trying to setup SslContext, and setting the session cachesize and timeout and other parameters in Netty 4.0.33.

After running quite some hours, this application hangs and not handling any https request.

Can anyone help me out, what will be the right configuration parameters...

This is my code snippet...

```
EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new EpollEventLoopGroup();

EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new EpollEventLoopGroup(); 

SslContext sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forServer(kmfget()).build();
sslCtx.sessionContext().setSessionCacheSize(1); 

sslCtx.sessionContext().setSessionTimeout(60);

ServerBootstrap sslB = new ServerBootstrap();

sslB.group(bossGroup, workerGroup).channel(EpollServerSocketChannel.class)

                    .childHandler(new NettyHttpServerInitializer(sslCtx))
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 100)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
                    .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
                    .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
Channel sslCh = sslB.bind(8475).sync().channel();
```

Comment: Can you get a thread dump after the application hang?

Comment: Check if you by any chance block the EventLoop threads with a thread-dump or use a profiler.